# How to create these shapes using css?

Tags: html, css

I want to develop such a design in CSS. How to do that?

[image: design]

Comment: border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but it looks like pointed at one side where I want to have it at bottom-center.

Answer (score 3):

The design is similar, that you want.

```css
.tear {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 80% 0 55% 50% / 55% 0 80% 50%;
  border-radius: 80% 0 55% 50% / 55% 0 80% 50%;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  background: #1abc9c;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 10ms;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 10ms;
  -o-transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 10ms;
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) 10ms;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-10.313240312354818deg) rotateY(-5.156620156177409deg) rotateZ(-32.0856365273261deg)   ;
  transform: rotateX(-10.313240312354818deg) rotateY(-5.156620156177409deg) rotateZ(-32.0856365273261deg)   ;
}
```

```html
<div class="tear">Aditya</div>
```

Comment: That's the cool! Even I was trying for this little tiled drop. Thank a lot for your help...!!

Answer (score 0):

To make rounded corners, use `border-radius`,
to rotate the element use `transform: rotate()`,
It's best to put that on a pseudo element, so you won't have to rotate the parent `(45deg)` and the child `(-45deg)`.

```css
.shape {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.shape::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: green;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; /* put bigger z-index than the pseudo element*/
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```